# Tmux set-hook session-attached doesn't work with choose-tree mode

Tags: bash, tmux

I've sat a hook in `.tmux.conf`. The assumption was it should reconnect last SSH session after tmux session was attached. The problem is it works only when attaching session using `tmux a -t session_name`. When attaching session from choose-tree mode the script is not called.

```
set-hook -g session-attached 'run-shell "/opt/scripts/tmux_ssh_reconnext.sh"'
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if inside a TMUX session
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
    # Check if SSH connection exists
    if [[ $(hostname) != "my_tmux_server" ]]; then
        echo "SSH connection already established."
    else
        # Reconnect last SSH session
        tmux send-keys -t 0 !ssh Enter
        echo "SSH session reconnected inside TMUX."
    fi
else
    echo "Not inside a TMUX session."
fi
```

Comment: I don't get the logic of this script. I think `hostname` run by your tmux server does not depend on any SSH connection, it will always give you the name of the machine where the tmux server runs. Or do you use the same script on the SSH server side and you want the same piece of code to work differently on both ends? (probably not). I suspect *maybe* you think that `ssh`-ing to elsewhere will make your tmux magically run commands (like `hostname`) there. If so then this is the first thing to fix here.

Comment: @XorOrNor I might be mistaken but `session-attached` hook does not exists. Did you mean `client-attached`? With `set-hook -g session-attached` it shows "invalid option".